# Creating a Grails URLMapping for all methods in a controller?

Tags: grails, groovy, url-mapping

How do I create a urlmapping that maps controller A essentially as controller B?

I thought something like this would work, but no dice.

```
  "/my/"(controller: 'other', action: '*')
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "that maps controller A essentially as controller B"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify a controller in UrlMappings, leave off the trailing "Controller" (e.g. `"my"`, instead of `"myController"`).  You also need some way of choosing which action.

You probably want something like `"/my/$action?"(controller: 'my')`, which maps urls like `/my/foo` to the foo action in MyController.  The trailing question mark means the action part of the url is optional; `/my` will trigger `MyController.index`.

Note that the grails convention is already to map `/my` to `MyController` with the default mapping `"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{}`, so you don't need a special UrlMapping for your example.  You might want to consider just using the defaults and follow the convention.

Comment: You're right. My example was exceptionally poor. It would only make sense if I was mapping MycontrollerController to MyController. :P